# Изменить значение $_COOKIE

Tags: php, cookie

При входе задаётся какое-то количество куков.

```
setcookie("id", $ds['id'], time()+999999, "/");
```

В ходе работы необходимо поменять их значения, однако время необходимо оставить.

```
$_COOKIE['id'] = $new;
```

Так не работает. Как осуществить?

Comment: Вы не сможете таким образом изменить куку. Используйте setcookie.  
И маленький вопрос: куку Вы хотите изменить у клиента, или промежуточное ее значение на сервере?

Comment: На сервере. Запись идёт в бд через ajax, и хотелось бы чтоб это же значение и в куку пошло.

Comment: Тогда Вы хотите поменять как раз таки не на сервере, а у клиента. Готовых решений изменить куки с помощью JavaScript тьма.  
То есть из ответа сервера на аякс-запрос читаете пришедшие куки и устанавливаете их уже документу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Так не работает.

Работает:

```
<pre>
<?php
print_r( $_COOKIE );
$_COOKIE['KCFINDER_showname'] = 'off';
print_r( $_COOKIE );
?>
</pre>
```

Вывод:

```
Array
(
    [KCFINDER_showname] => on
    [KCFINDER_showsize] => off
    [KCFINDER_showtime] => off
    [KCFINDER_order] => name
    [KCFINDER_orderDesc] => off
    [KCFINDER_view] => thumbs
    [KCFINDER_displaySettings] => off
    [CKFinder_Path] => Files:/:1
    [CKFinder_Settings] => TNNDS
    [absoluteURL] => 0
)
Array
(
    [KCFINDER_showname] => off
    [KCFINDER_showsize] => off
    [KCFINDER_showtime] => off
    [KCFINDER_order] => name
    [KCFINDER_orderDesc] => off
    [KCFINDER_view] => thumbs
    [KCFINDER_displaySettings] => off
    [CKFinder_Path] => Files:/:1
    [CKFinder_Settings] => TNNDS
    [absoluteURL] => 0
)
```

> Как осуществить?

Уточните, что именно нужно. На клиенте вы куку так не поменяете. А для работы в своём коде лучше считать значение в отдельную переменную и работать с ней, ибо нечего лазить в суперглобальные массивы.

Comment: Переменные тогда использовать как глобальные?

Answer (score 0):

Сами куки хранятся на клиенте (в хранилище браузера), и при каждом запросе браузер в заголовке передаёт имя и значения кук строкой в таком формате "key1=val1;key2=val2". Для того, чтобы с сервера установить куку, на клиенте также используется специальный заголовок, в котором передаются имя, значение и время жизни куки. В PHP такую функцию выполняет метод setcookie. На сервере нет никакого механизма изменения куки, есть возможность получить куки, и установить куки.

> однако время необходимо оставить

Следовательно, если задачей является "изменение" куки, то Вам нужно хранить время создания куки на своей стороне.

P.S. Массив $_COOKIE хранит значения полученных кук, Вы конечно можете менять эти значения и добавлять новые через этот массив, но на клиент эти изменения не передадутся, для установки используйте только setcookie